# adding exponent numbers to R plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

Is there a way to add an exponent number into the middle of an axis label?
If I use

```
expression(paste("Total Biomass (mg/", m^{3})))
```

I cant get it to look like `Total Biomass (mg/m3)` (imagine the 3 is small). It will only look like `Total Biomass (mg/m3` without the `)` and I also can't create a label that needs to say `"Total Abundance (x106 cells/L)"` (imagine the 6 is small).

```
# create a dataset
set.seed(123)
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
df <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
df

# Grouped
ggplot(df, aes(fill = condition, y = value, x = specie)) +
  labs(x = "Lakes", y = expression(paste("Total Plankton Biomass (mg/", m^{3})))
```

Comment: You miss the right parenthesis `")"` in `paste`, i.e. `y = expression(paste("Total Plankton Biomass (mg/", m^{3}, ")"))`